# Android adjustResize layout resize with soft keyboard

Tags: android, layout, android-softkeyboard

I'm struggling to get a small EditText along with two buttons aligned to the bottom of the screen *or* bottom of software keyboard. Basically my problem is that every time I open up my activity (flagged with **adjustResize | stateAlwaysVisible**) and layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:gravity="bottom" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/soft_input_edit_placeholder">
        <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText1">
            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:weightSum="2" android:id="@+id/soft_input_layout_buttons">
        <Button android:layout_width="0dp" android:text="xxx Submit xxx" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/soft_input_button_submit" android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_width="0dp" android:text="xxx Cancel xxx" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/soft_input_button_cancel" android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The keyboard slides up, it resizes the activity so that **only the edit text is visible**, and when I hide it (at least the keyboard has a button that allows me to hide it), layout remains in position, that is, it never slides back down, leaving half of the screen uncovered.

I read that in most cases the alignment is achieved by introducing some scalable control to the layout, but I don't really wish to have any form of ListView there; I tried using RelativeLayout, still no go. Embedding one into the other - still no luck. I'd be very thankful for any suggestions you may have, I'm running out of ideas..

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was all in selected themes. My activity had a full-screen theme applied in the manifest (and I had no idea it might affect the view in this way); changing it to non-fullscreen has solved my problems (although it can't be just *any other* theme)

I achieved my goal by setting activity theme to **Theme.Translucent** and layout theme to **Theme** (no theme at all); applying **@android:drawable/bottom_bar** to the main LinearLayout and finally setting the main layout's gravity to **bottom** gave me the results  I was looking for.